# How to stop execution of all cells in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Suppose I executed all cells in a Jupyter Notebook, and want to interrupt the computation in the middle. How can I stop the execution of all cells?

"Kernel interrupt" only interrupts the execution of the current cell, but then immediately continues with all remaining cells. Instead, I do not want to execute all remaining cells after hitting "Kernel interrupt". How can I do that?

I am running version 4.2.3 with Python 3.5.2, packaged by conda-forge

Comment: It sounds like a bug that it continues executing cells after interrupt. Can you [open an issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues).

Answer (score 49):

If you know it beforehand, where you want to stop (e.g have code below that takes long and doesn't need to be executed every run),
you can add a

```
    raise SystemExit("Stop right there!")
```

whereever you want to stop.

Everything below isn't executed, since an exception has been thrown and when using the SystemExit Exception no stacktrace is shown by default.
*The kernel doesn't exit, so you can still execute everything by hand afterwards.*

Comment: You could even just dump in an undefined variable (I like `stop`), which results in a NameError being thrown for you. Short and sweet.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution is to just use `assert False` which stops execution at that point in the code. The best practice is to put this in a cell of its own, so you can stop and start the code around this.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

we can just click on the `interrupt the kernel` it will stop the computation.

Answer (score 0):

Put in comment (highlight and press Ctrl-/) the instruction(s) responsible for running -- or, faster, comment the whole cell -- and re-run the cell (Ctrl-Enter). This will stop running and of course the output. You can then un-comment the affected part.
This is much less painful than killing and restarting the kernel.

(Note that just clearing the output with [Esc]+'O' won't stop it.)

Comment: Sorry about that, @Thur. You should better say though that it does not work FOR YOU. ***I never, never, never post a solution if I have not tested it previously ***

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `exit()` since to me it is cleaner than raising an exception

Comment: doesn't work in jupyter-lab

Answer (score 0):

`raise SystemExit` from dCSeven is a good solution. If you don’t want to see the Python error message, you can wrap your code in a `try..except` block.

```py
def do_what_you_have_to_do():
    i_want_to_stop = True
    if i_want_to_stop:
        raise SystemExit("I just wanted to stop!")

try:
    do_what_you_have_to_do()
except SystemExit as _e:
    print(_e)
```

Answer (score -3):

One simple trick to get rid of this problem, is to press "ctrl+a" to select all the code of that particular cell you want to stop the execution of and press "ctrl+x" to cut the entire cell code.
Now the cell is empty and just the empty cell is executed.
Afterwards just paste the code by "ctrl+v" and now your problem would be solved.